# PHP how to make Youtube like id's for urls?

Tags: php, hash, youtube

I'm making a website which people can publish posts. In my database each post has an ID like 1, 2, 3 etc. but I would like to change them, like using a hash like Youtube does.

For example instead of http://localhost/post/1

They would go to http://localhost/post/hu9NA827z

Is there a method like hashing the numbers and decoding it?

Comment: There are lots of such algorithms. What specific properties do you need/want the URL to have? Short? Hard to guess? Easy to say out loud?

Comment: Short, easy, just not the ID. I want to be able to encrypt and decrypt it.

Comment: Haha 'htpp' are sure you know what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while you could encrypt/decrypt it doesn't make much sense (you're gonna make it slower without any real benefit). 
Waht you can do is to have the primary key in your DB to be a string and generate a hash for the id or add a new column with a unique index, save the hash there and search the posts by the hash column (and maybe keep the id for internal purposes). You can use complex algorithms or just md5(uniqid()), since this is not for security i wouldn't worry too much. Make sure that when creating a new post, the uniqueness is not being violated. Now you have another reason for an insertion to fail (the hash not being unique) so prepare for that.

Check:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Thank you for your response, but md5 is just too long, I would like something shorter like Imgur, Youtube and bit.ly use.

Comment: @Neme There is a benefict, which is also the reason YouTube uses it. It makes impossible to a robot / crawler to fetch or post comments on all videos from their website in sequence, because the algorithm that generates the IDs is unknown. It would be the easiest thing in the world to crawl YouTube if the videos were sequenced as `/v/1`,  `/v/2`, `/v/3` and so on.

Comment: Based on what you told that if I encoded and decoded an ID would be slower I used another column in the database and used substr(str_shuffle()) to generate a random hash, and when needed I will use the ID internally.

Comment: @user3769279 Slower is a relative term. Every new line of code will make it slower. Obviously calculating `1+2+3` is slower than `1+5` because theres one additional operation, yet you won't notice the difference even if you try hard. Computing a hash on a script that does a lot more time-costly stuff like fetching data from a database is not something to be considered a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no need for this hash to be secure, you can just use the PHP built-in hash function, `md5()`. I suggest using the timestamp as input:

`$id = md5(time());`

Just truncate it to make it shorter. I suggest you keep the original primary key an autoincrement integer and add this hash as a new column.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `hu9NA827z` is BASE64. Decoding it, you get a binary sequence of 6 bytes.

For instance:

```
base64_encode('123456') // = 'MTIzNDU2'
base64_decode('MTIzNDU2') // = '123456'
```

However, on YouTube, BASE64 is not being used to protect the information, its purpuse is just to serialize it into a human-readable ASCII format. The real message behind it is a 48-bit binary sequence.

This binary sequence is probably the encrypted version of what would be the video ID on a database, but what it really is only YouTube developers knows for sure and they certainly expect it to remain that way.

In your case, you could simply implement a similar system using one of the many two-way encryption methods offered in PHP like [MCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) that supports a lot of encryption algorithms of your choice including the very safe AES.